# Admin config screen without menu

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I want to create a sub config from some page on admin panel, eg:

I've set config menu this way:

```
add_menu_page( 'E+', 'CRE+', 8, 'cr_e_plus_user_config', 'cr_e_plus_user_config');
add_submenu_page( 'cr_e_plus_user_config', 'E+', 'Configurations', 8, 'cr_e_plus_user_config', 'cr_e_plus_user_config');
```

From `Configurations` page, I need to load another page when I click certain link. Now, I don't want this new page to be listed on menu, because it will need certain parameter before I can show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Admin pages are basically spoken nothing else then a hook to a function, so it is technically not a problem to add your own pages without making use of the menu.

I was not aware of an API function that allows you to register own pages with ease, but there is a helper function in Wordpress you can make use of: `get_plugin_page_hookname()` (undocumented function). Next to that, the hook needs to be registered in a global registry of all page hooks (`$GLOBALS['_registered_pages']`) so that it's rated valid when the page is requested.

I've wrapped that in some sample code, just save it into your `/wp-content/mu-plugins` folder: [admin_page_demo.php (Wordpress MU-Plugin Example)](http://gist.github.com/579350)

In there you can find a function `register_admin_page()` that can register any callback you need per the `admin_menu` hook. That's the important one, compare to [Adding Administration Menus (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus).

The function returns the URL of the new admin page. You wrote that you might need to add more parameters, so I thought that might be handy.

For the demo page I hardcoded into that example, the URL is: `/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=adminpagedemo_demo_page`.

Keep in mind, that you need to check for security for that page on your own because Wordpress does not. Something like

```
current_user_can( ... );
wp_die( __('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.') );
```

might be a helpful additional hint.

Comment: Is this best considered best practice? If I have administration forms in my plugin, should I use this method to register scripts for form processing, or should I be using wp-admin/edit.php or wp-admin/admin.php?action=myaction

Comment: @codecowboy: Please start a new question and reference this question in there. Leave a short message here as well. You will get much better feedback then.

Comment: I started a new question here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-create-plugin-administration-forms