# Does admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix work for nested paths to individual files?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, hooks

Can the hook `admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix` be used for a hook which has been created like `$hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname("my-quiz/lib/admin/$code_page", '' );`?

.. where `$code_page` is `somefilename.php`.

I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I think its probably because of the filepath ?

**UPDATE**

What gets registered by the above code is 'admin_page_my-quiz/lib/admin/question_form' but this only works in a page if you do:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=my-quiz/lib/admin/question_form.php&question=edit&question='.$question->ID); ?>" class='edit'>
        <?php _e('Edit', 'my-locale'); ?>
        </a>
```

**I have to add the .php suffix** for that link to work or I get the 'you do not have permission' error.

@t31os function outputs 'nmsi-quiz/lib/admin/question_form.php' and so this doesn't match 'admin_page_my-quiz/lib/admin/question_form'

this works - add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-'.'my-quiz/lib/admin/question_form.php', array($this,'enqueue_my_js'));

**Requested code:**

```
$plugin_scripts = array('question_form.php', 'manage_questions.php');

foreach($plugin_scripts as $code_page) {
    $hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname("my-quiz/lib/admin/$code_page", '' );
    $_registered_pages[$hookname] = true;
    //fb($hookname);

}
```

Comment: Can i see the code you're using to register the plugin pages please, ie. the `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` (or equivalent) calls..

Comment: Added. I realise that this is a non-standard way of doing things and that I am not using add_menu_page(). That's because I don't want these pages in the menu. I am aware of the issues surrounding this. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-create-plugin-administration-forms

Comment: The thing is, you can't have registered pages that don't exist in the menu, either way you'll lose some functionality if you just hack pages into the appropriate arrays, because core code does have expectations on registered pages to exist to some degree in both the `$menu` and `$submenu` arrays.. Might i suggest taking a look at the `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` functions to see what they do with the incoming data(this will give you an idea of WordPress does with pages registered using these functions - ie. what arrays it adds to, etc..)

Comment: I've added some sample code and further comments to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's really a question of whether that code is giving the correct hook name for the given page.

Here's a simple function you can use to output the hook suffix on each admin page, it will appear inside a red error box(so it'll be easy to spot) for admins only.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'print_admin_pagehook' );
function print_admin_pagehook() {
    global $hook_suffix;
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options') )
        return;
    ?>
    <div class="error"><p><?php echo $hook_suffix; ?></p></div>
    <?php 
}
```

Load up the page you're having a problem with and compare the value you see in the box with what you're getting back from the code you posted.

**Addition**
***Following on from my last comment, you can actually do something like this..***

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'testing_registered_pages', 100 );
function testing_registered_pages() {
    global $_registered_pages, $submenu;
    $plugin_scripts = array( 
        'Question Form' => array( 'page' => 'question_form', 'callback' => 'my_callback_1' ), 
        'Manage Questions' => array( 'page' => 'manage_questions', 'callback' => 'my_callback_2' ) 
    );
    foreach( $plugin_scripts as $title => $my_pages ) {
        $hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname("my-quiz/lib/admin/$my_pages[page]", 'my-quiz' );
        $_registered_pages[$hookname] = true;
        $submenu['my-quiz'][] = array( $title, 'manage_options', "my-quiz/lib/admin/$my_pages[page]", $title );
        add_action( $hookname, $my_pages['callback'] );
    }
}

// Remove the add_action to reference actual files, leave in place to use a callback function
```

...there's just one problem with this approach, and that's in being able to defeat the capability requirements of the page(s).

Take this URL.

```
example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-quiz/lib/admin/manage_questions
```

We can defeat the cap check by querying for..

```
example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-quiz/lib/admin/manage_questions.php
```

If we switch the code from earlier to use the file extension instead, eg..

```
    $plugin_scripts = array( 
        'Question Form' => array( 'page' => 'question_form.php', 'callback' => 'my_callback_1' ), 
        'Manage Questions' => array( 'page' => 'manage_questions.php', 'callback' => 'my_callback_2' ) 
    );
```

..and optionally disable callbacks, ie. use a real file..

```
// add_action( $hookname, $my_pages['callback'] );
```

..this then gives us..

```
example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-quiz/lib/admin/manage_questions.php
```

..it's still possible to defeat capability requirements using..

```
example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-quiz/lib/admin/manage_questions
```

Regardless of whether you use an actual file or a callback function, in either case the capability requirements(as above) can be circumvented(obviously this would not be desired behaviour).