# Silently register plugin pages

Tags: plugin-development, admin-menu

I am developing one of my first plugins, and have come across a error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

The plugin has a wizard that uses several forms, obviously I don't want people selecting later forms using the menu.

Is there a way to "silently" register a page? Basically, register the page without having it appear in any menu.

(I don't like my work around)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mighty [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) holds the answers:

1. If you're running into the »You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.« message in a `wp_die()` screen, then you've hooked too early. The hook you should use is `admin_menu`.
2. `$parent_slug`: Use `NULL` or set to `options.php` if you want to create a page that doesn't appear in any menu

Comment: I am rolling my eyes and laughing at myself. I wouldn't have thought to look on the "add_submenu_page" to figure out how *not* add a submenu page.

Question answered... thanks.

Comment: You can also register a page as normal and remove it using `remove_menu_page()`. The page will still be accessible by URL, but will not show up in the menu

Comment: Hmm... I think this may be the question I was really asking

[link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7812/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-create-plugin-administration-forms[/link]

Comment: It seems using remove_menu_page() does actually prevent access. Codex seems to suggest it shouldn't also. I'm looking into it because I really need to register 30 pages but only show 5 in the main plugin menu. The rest are offered in tabbed menus. I've just posted a YouTube about my problem and any solution will be added to CSV 2 POST if you want to go looking at code.