# Proper way to create an administration page without adding it to the menu

Tags: plugin-development, admin, admin-menu

From what I've seen around the code, you can do this by hooking a function on `admin_init`, do you stuff and then `die()`.

Is there a better way that follows "WP best practices" I'm missing here?

The page should not have any default body content, like the dashboard sidebar, but the admin scripts/CSS should be loaded normally.

Comment: when you use `die()` you can rest assured that is not the **proper way**

Comment: That's why I'm asking for alternatives

Comment: Unless the administration page does not have any link in menu, how it will be accessed? if you want to access that page directly (putting URL in the address bar) and you don't want to embed the page inside wp-admin's layout, (i dont know exact way, honestly), i guess you can create a separate php file and include `wp-config.php` so that you can wp environments. from that page, you can handle the configurations. but its also surely NOT best practice.

Comment: you can check this page. here i see some guidelines http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1778/admin-config-screen-without-menu?rq=1

Comment: Also, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65207/plugin-create-a-page-without-it-appearing-in-the-side-menu/65211

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do a simple trick like this:

- Create an administration page, just like normally using `add_menu` hook with default or low priority
- Hook to `admin_menu` with **higher** priority and remove that admin menu item (or you can use a plugin like [Hide Admin Menu](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/hide-admin-menu/) to do that)

Removing admin menu after creating doesn't block you from accessing that page, it just hide the item in the menu, meaning if other people don't know the page slug (which you can make it unique and hard to guess) they can't access the page.

Answer (score 0):

- remove all admin menu
- remove all dashboard widget
- disable upgrade notification

you'll have blank dashboard and do your stuff

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-wordpress-dashboard-hacks