# Plugin - create a page without it appearing in the side menu

Tags: plugin-development, add-submenu-page

I am currently using add_submenu_page to add pages for my plugin. However, I wish to create a page that don't appear in the admin menu, is that possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the **`parent_slug`** property to **`null`**, example;

```
   add_submenu_page( 
          null            // -> Set to null - will hide menu link
        , 'Page Title'    // -> Page Title
        , 'Menu Title'    // -> Title that would otherwise appear in the menu
        , 'administrator' // -> Capability level
        , 'menu_handle'   // -> Still accessible via admin.php?page=menu_handle
        , 'page_callback' // -> To render the page
    );
```

This will hide the sub menu page from your parent (top level) menu link.

<strike>It does not state this in the **Codex** entry for [**`add_submenu_page`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) though.</strike>

It now states this in the **Codex** entry for [**`add_submenu_page`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) (thanks goto Ian Dunn).

Comment: It does now :) It only takes a minute to update it.

Comment: Good lad, thanks. I was trying to do that but having trouble with log-in.

Comment: You can also set the parent page to `options.php` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Thanks @Pippin, I've also added that to the Codex with example code.